# Get Host Address in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to get my host address on my controller which type is POST. Please check bellow the controller example. Please note I am using asp.net core 2.1

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult PasswordReset(ResetPassword data)
{
    string myurl = //how can i store http host address on this variable?
    return View()
}
```

Comment: Ddi you try checking the properties on `Request`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

In the controller:

```
string myHostUrl = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}";
```

Outside the controller:

```
public class YourClass 
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   public YourClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   public void YourMethod()
   {
      string myHostUrl = $"{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host}";
   }
}
```

And then register `IHttpContextAccessor` in the Startup class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Or you can also register as follows

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: What if I am running background jobs? In this case `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext = null` so how can I get the same properties?

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis Good question. You can store the host URL in `appsettings.json` file and then use it.

Comment: Is there really no helper available to generate a url?

Answer (score 8):

You can get by accessing Request

```
string myurl = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}";
```

Answer (score 1):

// to get complete host

```
string host = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In case, if your application is hosted inside a virtual directory, 

    public class ABC
    {
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
       public ABC(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
         {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
         }

       public void GetFullAppHostUrl()
         {
         string fullUrl=  $"{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host}{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.PathBase}";
     }
    }
```